# How to find the region of convergence of the Laurent series of $f(z)=(z-3)\sin\frac{1}{z+2}$ at $z=-2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laurent-series

I know that

$$
f(z)=(z-3)\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(z+2)^{2n+1}}
$$

But I am not sure how to find the region of convergence $f(z)$. Is there a way to find the region of convergence for $f(z)$?

Comment: What do you know about the region of convergence of the sine series?

Comment: @LutzL, its $0<|z|<\infty$.

Comment: What is the problem with the convergence of the series for $\sin(z)$ at $z=0$?

Comment: @LutzL, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Why did you exclude $z=0$ in the region of convergence for the sine series?

Comment: @LutzL, Is the region of convergence $0<|z+2|<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be able to explain this.